# converting text file in to Json

Tags: python, json

**we are getting output in this format**

```
2020-11-19 12:00:01,414 - INFO - clusterDC -Backup started
2020-11-19 12:00:01,415 - Debug - executing command: /opt/couchbase/bin/cbbackupmgr backup --archive /backup/clusterDC --repo clusterDC_date --cluster nodedc --username user --threads 16
2020-11-19 12:00:01,414 - INFO - clusterDC - Backup Succeeded. Backup successfully completed.
```

**But now we want them in below JSON format**.

```
"backup":[
   {
    "server_name":"nodedc",
    "status":"Success/Failed",
    "backup_start_time":"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmmuu",
    "cluster_name":"clusterDC",
    "location":"/backup/clusterDc/clusterDC_date",
    "backup_end_time":"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:mmmuu"
    }
```

Comment: And what are your tries ? SO is not a place that does your homeworks ;)

Comment: The structure looks regular. So try doing regular expressions (https://regexr.com) and come back if you can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do this. One would be to parse the your output into a a list then use numpy to convert that to json. For parsing, just use string manipulation (maybe regex if needed) to populate your list.

Answer (score 0):

If the output follows the same format each time:

```py
#output = raw output
output = [line.split() for line in output.splitlines()]

backup = {}
backup["server_name"] = text[1][14]
backup["status"] = text[2][8]
backup["backup_start_time"] = f"{text[0][0]} {text[0][1].replace(',', ':')}"
backup["cluster_name"] = text[0][5]
backup["location"] = f"{text[1][10]}/{text[1][12]}"
backup["backup_end_time"] = f"{text[2][0]} {text[2][1].replace(',', ':')}"

backup = {'backup': [backup]}
print(backup)
```

Output:

```py
{'backup': [{'server_name': 'nodedc', 'status': 'Succeeded.', 'backup_start_time': '2020-11-19 12:00:01:414', 'cluster_name': 'clusterDC', 'location': '/backup/clusterDC/clusterDC_date', 'backup_end_time': '2020-11-19 12:00:01:414'}]}
```